# Qt to .Net integration: resize issue

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, qt

I am writing a Qt widget that should be integrated to .Net application.
I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970061(v=vs.110).aspx) article to write a wrapper class for WPF.
The problem I've faced is that the widget does not occupy the whole space allocated for it. It is easily visible on the attached image.

[image: .Net resize issue]

I wonder if there is a simple solution to this problem that does not involve the usage of COM/ActiveX, because I would like to keep my class easily visible in .Net?

Comment: The article you followed offers an unnecessarily circuitous route via native windows and such. That's a performance killer and not needed. Qt can render your widget into a `QImage`, all you need is to interface that into a WPF control; similarly you can translate the events from the WPF control and pass them to your `QWidget`.

Comment: @Kuba Interesting, but this approach also seems to be quite indirect.

Comment: It's not really all that indirect, internally WPF does more-or-less the same thing. Modern UIs pretty much render to bitmaps, and composite the bitmaps and some geometry using either the CPU or GPU...

Comment: @Kuba Actually in my case it would perform slower, because as I mentioned in my comment to Elmar, I need Qt data visualization module, which in turn uses OpenGL. And for OpenGL (as well as other Graphics library) rendering to texture is slower than rendering to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use COM objects and interfaces to get the job done. There is no way around this as you have to manipulate the form to embed an existing application. There are a lot of information regarding this on MSDN and stackoverflow, but this implementation does not come without side unwanted side effects one being a good integrated look and feel.

You can center the embedded win32 Qt application/widget and then color your WPF container accordingly, but as you are still busy writing the Qt widget I would advise you to rather do your whole application in WPF and c# as this would have a much better look and feel, as well as save on licensing costs for Qt Commercial use. By using WPF, you are making your application Windows dependent anyway. If you are using Qt for the c++ performance benefits, rather write small c++ cli applications and execute them via c# code where necessary.

Comment: [This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-dotnet.html) article doesn't seem to force you into using COM only. It is said there, that you have a choice whether write your own wrappers or use ActiveQt.

Comment: I understand completely what you are trying to do and that it is possible, but why would you want to do this and make your life difficult? Why use to completely different technologies when both of them can (mostly) do what the other can? I'm not trying to funny, I'm just trying to get your perspective on things.

Comment: I need to figure out how hard it is to embed a Qt widget into .Net application and what problems it causes.
What I need is a 3D Surface graph visualization (from Qt Data visualization module). I know there are C#-based solutions like SciChart, but it doesn't fit our needs.
And since the company is thinking on buying Qt license anyway, I was asked to carry out this small research.

Comment: That is totally understandable. I used Qt back in university and it is quite a versatile framework with a lot of great GUI widgets. I really hope you manage to find a solution.